# Synchronously getting response from longrunning aws lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

[image]

I'm experimenting with nodejs puppeteer and the serverless framework following https://hackernoon.com/a-crash-course-on-serverless-with-node-js-632b37d58b44 . I have a puppeteer function that takes around 45 seconds to run and returns some data.

I have a function called main in index.js using puppeteer which I have tested locally and is working correctly, which includes:

```
async function main() {

  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: 'wss://chrome.browserless.io/'
  });
  var page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36');

...................

obj_arr.push(obj);

}
```

my handler.ls function includes:

```
'use strict';

// module.exports.main = async event => {
module.exports.main = event => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: 'main function executed!',
        main: module.exports.main(),
        input: event,
      },
      null,
      2
    ),
  };
```

Using the serverless framework I've uploaded the code to amazon lambda without error. I tried changing the boilerplate code in handler.js to try to run the function synchronously and avoid having to store the output somewhere else. I'm getting the error in the screenshot. Is this possible and if so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since api gateway has 29 seconds limit (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) - you can't wait for a response which exceeds that limit. WebSocket API's may work for you. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html or you may try async invocation(api gateway) + use some state etc

Comment: Thanks, assuming I could bring the function run time to 28 seconds , does the code above look right to work synchronously?

Comment: If the lambda function works %100 under 29 seconds - yes you can get that response from the invoked application. Lambda has 15 minutes max limit - but since lambda can be used with different triggers such as kinesis, s3 etc - 15 minutes make sense. But using api gateway as trigger is not one of the valid use case for long running processes.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm not knowledgeble with lambda and node, but it seems from reading a number of articles that its very common to use an S3 bucket to save results from long running processes, if I can't get the function under 29 seconds, what is the easiest way to store and retrieve results in your opinion?

Comment: Let's say you have an application - that makes a request to api gateway for this process. You make api gateway async that triggers lambda - and after your lambda completes it's process -> you make a callback request to your application (opening an endpoint for lambda to make a response back - just like a webhook) - if you want you may store in s3, dynamodb that results  - and read that results periodically from your requester application. making as webhook would be easiest - other options require to install sdk, make cron jobs, read/parse etc.

Comment: So you are saying make an http request from the lambda function back to the triggering server? because I'm using node maybe using one of https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html

Comment: That’s one of the useful ways to consider - websockets is one other way to do it. You make an async request to an api and it returns back when it’s done. You may use node’s request or request premise library. You may use an identifer while making a request to lamda and when it requests back you get that identifer to use to complete your “previously sync request”.

Comment: Thank you. In my case my server is a google apps script account, which according to a quick search does not support websockets yet.

Comment: Then you may open an endpoint(apply some authentication for security reasons) and make a request to that endpoint after your lambda ends its puppeteer work.